# Javascript inserting weird newLine character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ascii

I have an array named `verses` that contains strings created from an ajax response. The array is created like this:

```
verses.push(splitStr[i].replace('\n',''));
```

Later I create some `<span>` elements and append the values from the array. However the last element from array always has a strange behavior because it contains a hidden `new line` character in ASCII it has the code `10` (checked that in the console). Now when I print in the console log the last element from the array a get this result: `"string"`. Then I create the span element that contains this string and later when I retrieve back the value from span I get:

```
"string
"
```

That's because when creating the span it always inserts this strange `new line` character. So in the source code the span looks like:

```
<span class="answer" onclick="checkAnswer(this)">potopului
</span>
```

You can see that the closing tag is on the next line.

In the console I used some break points and I got this value extracted from span: `"string↵"`

Now, has anyone any idea why when creating this span javascript inserts a `new line` character and why does it happen only with the last element from array?

The code used to create the span elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i!=phtml) {
            tags.push("<span class='answer' onclick='checkAnswer(this)'>"+generateRandom(pos)+'</span>'); 
            //generate a  string from the array different from the one with position pos
        }else{
            tags.push("<span class='answer'  onclick='checkAnswer(this)'>"+verses[pos].replace('\n','')+'</span>');
        }
    }
    var output='';
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        output = output + tags[i];
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('v-options')[0].innerHTML = output;
```

The `checkAnswer()` function:

```
function checkAnswer(e){
    var text = e.innerHTML;
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-word')[pos];
    if (text == verses[pos]) {
        input.value = verses[pos];
        input.setAttribute('disabled','');
    }
    console.log(":"+text.substring(0, text.length-1) + ":"+verses[pos]+":");
}
```

Comment: If you want to scrub *all* newlines, it's `.replace(/\n/g, '')` — your code is only replacing the **first** newline.

Comment: try to `.replace(/\n\r|\n|\r/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks, @MysterX! That worked!

Comment: @MysterX, you can post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @AlinCrescensCiurea, answer created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes line breaks are printed in different styles. Commonly it is a combination of two special characters `\n` and `\r` so you just need to check all possible types of newline combinations or their lost broken parts. Try to change your `RegExp` to match them all :

```
splitStr[i].replace(/\n\r|\n|\r/g, '')
```